# How to compute this huge Correlation Matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, ff, pearson, bigdata

I have a huge matrix with nrow=144 and ncol=156267 containing numbers and I would like to compute the correlation between all the columns. This can be done using the `bigcor` function described here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/bigcor-large-correlation-matrices-in-r/.

After making the `bigcor` function I ran:

```
bigcor(Mbig2, nblocks = 1611, verbose = TRUE)
```

This leads to the following errors:

> Error in if (length < 0 || length > .Machine$integer.max) stop("length must be between 1 and .Machine$integer.max") : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In ff(vmode = "single", dim = c(NCOL, NCOL)) :

My questions are: 1) Is this even feasible? Is there a way of escaping the error?

Comment: That means a matrix of 156,267 rows and 156,267 columns.  (It's symmetric, so you can divide roughly by two.)  Rather large, agreed?

Comment: Do you mean dividing by the diagonal? I thought that was a given. Yes, it is rather large.

Comment: No, i do not mean dividing by the diagonal.  Correlation matricies have 1.0 on the diagonal, by definition, and off-diagonal terms that range from -1 to 1.  I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: There is mention of this error at http://www.bytemining.com/2010/05/hitting-the-big-data-ceiling-in-r/ and http://brainchronicle.blogspot.ca/2013/02/large-correlation-in-parallel.html - it seems to be a limitation of R.  Is there a reason for calculating such a large correlation matrix? Perhaps there is a way around this if could let us know what you will be using this correlation matrix for.

Comment: Thanks @jav, It seems to be a limitation of R.

Comment: @jav,
The idea behind doing this matrix was: Each column represent a block of genomic DNA that might be linked to other blocks depending on the Correlation result. I wanted to 1st compute all the possible correlation values and then explore them to analyze which blocks are most linked. 
Now I think this naive approach is not the correct one. I'll try to separate some selected blocks -columns- first and then compute the correlation. The downside is that this is no longer naive, as blocks are 1st selected.

Comment: Do you know a rough cutoff for minimum correlation value? e.g. 0.05 or something? It might seriously reduce the size of the result.